# Deleted question with positive score: when does my rep update

Tags: discussion

After a (for me) unusual spate of unpleasant back and forth with several users, I decided to delete an answer I wrote although it had a +11-1 vote count. However I am not seeing the negative impact on rep count that I was expecting. I just hit the rep cap for the day - which is why the timing of when the - 108 points would happen is of some interest.

What should I expect?

Comment: Within an hour usually

Comment: OK - so five hours without update is a bit long...

Comment: Yes, that's a bit long. But if I were you, I wouldn't start worrying until it's been a day. After a day, it should definitely update.

Comment: Wait, I'm remembering something.... I recall reading that changes in rep due to deleting a post are applied to you retroactively. So your daily rep cap is still hit, but whenever you got the rep from the answer is when it'll count as being removed

Comment: Is your rep 108 points lower than before you deleted the post?

Comment: @Jimnosperm - I can't say for sure... I would have expected to see a delta show up (like it does when a user is removed, for example).

Comment: There is a way to trigger a manual rep update and I can't for the life of me find the link for it. Grrr.

Comment: Woot! Found it. Answer on the way.

Comment: How old was the post? Points gained on posts that are older than some threshold (I think 6 months) are *not* lost on deletion. This resulted from a hard fought comprimize over the removal of some questions from the early days of Stack Overflow when, years later, the site culture had changed substantially from the wild west days of the public beta and its immediate aftermath.

Comment: Hmmm ... See the heading "What else should I know about deleted posts?" on http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/2509. I was wrong on the time, it is 60 days.

Comment: @dmckee - it wasn't that old; I wrote the original on March 15. And I don't see any of the upvotes in the phys.se.com/reputation page so it seems some adjustment was done - except that the "daily journal" doesn't make mention of the loss of rep.

Comment: Floris, would you mind letting me have the link to the deleted question?

Comment: Floris, thanks and I have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, it took me way too long to find this considering how simple it was. If you are logged in, visit:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation

and it will update your reputation plus give you the actual info on how it is calculated. Waaaay down at the bottom is a summary of reputation changes. This should, hopefully, fix the caching issue and trigger the correct calculation of your reputation.

There is a related question [on the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236420/when-will-my-reputation-update) which seems to indicate a bug existed ~8 months ago in the update script when users hit the rep cap and then lost some votes somewhere. The answer there says the bug is/was acknowledged but I haven't found whether it has been fixed or not.

If manually updating the reputation doesn't fix it, maybe there is still a problem somewhere and this needs to be escalated.

But that's above my pay grade.

Reading into that mother meta question, particularly the comments under it, it seems that the manual refresh button was removed from that reputation page I gave and the only way to trigger a recalc (at that time) was to delete/undelete one of your own answers. Again, no idea if this bug is still around or not, but you could always give that a shot and see if things update.

Comment: Observations: 1) rep given in /reputation page matches value in status bar etc; 2) there are NO entries for the question ID that I deleted (suggesting that the deletion did take place "retrospectively"); 3) there is no indication of a change in rep on my status. So I guess my issue is solved for now - @Jimnosperm was correct, and the only issue is that there is no "journal entry" that I can see.

Comment: That page used to be documented and useful before the rep revamp where most of the necessity for rep recalcs was fixed. I think everything is _supposed_ to update almost automatically now, except perhaps deletes, so that page isn't supposed to be used anymore (hence the lack of documentation)